# Сброс redux при рендеринге другого компонента

Tags: reactjs, redux

У меня есть redux-хранилище, которое хранит в себе список продуктов, который покупатель добавил к себе в корзину. При переходе на корзину(рендере компонента cart) redux сбрасывает свое состояние
Использую react-router-dom 6-12-1

Comment: Сам редакс делать этого не может. Что то вы в коде, видимо, сделали не так